# Is there any way to invoke subview's function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SubView()
            
            Button("Invoke"){
                ...// invoke subview's function
            }
        }
    }
}
struct SubView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("SubView")
    }
    func changeSubView() {
        //...
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example. I don't want to use **@State** to control or pass function as a parameter.
Is there any other way?

Comment: You can assign `SubView()` to a property, like `struct ContentView: View { let subView = SubView(); var body: some View {...` then in the VStack `subView; Button("Invoke") { subView.changeSubview() }`

Comment: It works , thank you.